# Passing msiexec switches through vbscript

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer, silent-installer

I'm trying to silently install MSI packages through a vbscript but when I try to pass switches through all I get is the blank command prompt and the Windows Installer tooltip opens.

Here's a couple ways I've tried this below, but I get the same thing each time.

[image: Windows Installer tooltip that comes up when running script]

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /c msiexec" & "/i" & Chr(34) & "AppleApplicationSupport64.msi" & Chr(34) & "/quiet" & "/norestart"
objShell.Run "cmd /c msiexec" & "/i" & Chr(34) & "AppleMobileDeviceSupport6464.msi" & Chr(34) & "/quiet" & "/norestart"
objShell.Run "cmd /c msiexec" & "/i" & Chr(34) & "iTunes6464.msi" & Chr(34) & "/quiet" & "/norestart"
objShell.Run "cmd /c msiexec" & "/i" & Chr(34) & "Bonjour64.msi" & Chr(34) & "/quiet" & "/norestart"
objShell.Run "cmd /c msiexec" & "/i" & Chr(34) & "AppleSoftwareUpdate.msi" & Chr(34) & "/quiet" & "/norestart"
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Second way I tried

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""%userprofile%\Desktop\Deployment\AppleApplicationSupport64.msi""") + "/quiet" + "/norestart"
objShell.Run("""%userprofile%\Desktop\Deployment\AppleMobileDeviceSupport6464.msi""") + "/quiet" + "/norestart"
objShell.Run("""%userprofile%\Desktop\Deployment\iTunes6464.msi""") + "/quiet" + "/norestart"
objShell.Run("""%userprofile%\Desktop\Deployment\Bonjour64.msi""") + "/quiet" + "/norestart"
objShell.Run("""%userprofile%\Desktop\Deployment\AppleSoftwareUpdate.msi""") + "/quiet" + "/norestart"
Set objShell = Nothing
```

It doesn't seem to go past the msiexec command. How can I get it to run the entire string together the full command to install the packages?

Comment: I think you need a space `( )` between the msi switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing some spaces in your commands that you are sending to the shell. I'll just examine the first command as an example. Here's what you wrote:

```
objShell.Run "cmd /c msiexec" & "/i" & Chr(34) & "AppleApplicationSupport64.msi" & Chr(34) & "/quiet" & "/norestart"
```

And here is the command that that statement builds:

```
msiexec/i"AppleApplicationSupport64.msi"/quiet/norestart
```

You are getting that `Windows Installer` window because it doesn't understand the command with no spaces. Instead, add some spaces inside the string like so:

```
   objShell.Run "cmd /c msiexec " & "/i " & Chr(34) & "AppleApplicationSupport64.msi" & Chr(34) & " /quiet" & " /norestart"
```

The above will format the command as:

`msiexec /i "AppleApplicationSupport64.msi" /quiet /norestart`

That should resolve your issue.